# Color-picker for Windows Forms applications

Tags: .net, winforms, colors, controls, color-picker

Is there a built-in color-picker in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, in the common dialog control.  This control contains a `ColorDialog` color picker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It is a dialog window for picking a color. What control can be used to allow user to see currently selected color?

Comment: @Peter Upon selecting a color from the dialog, it will return you an object of type `Color`.  You can then display that in any medium you'd like, such as a picture box.